# How to Locally Recreate Functionality of Server Side Code

Tags: c#, asp.net

My institution has software which has a web component.  There is a webpage with an associated asp.cs file with a function defined in it.  This function takes in some input, returns a bool and modifies the "results" property of the input object with some valuable information on the process.  I would like to obtain the same results of this function, that would typically be served on the page, using code independent of vendor.  Is it in anyway possible to call a function defined in an asp.cs file on a server?  I could potentially take the code out and adjust it to suit my needs, but that would involve resolving all of its dependencies, which I can imagine could get messy.

What would be my best option in hijacking this code?

Comment: so with locally, you mean executing in the browser, JavaScript-wise? page code in asp.cs is usually partial, that is backed up by compiled "codebehind" in one or more dlls.

Comment: Sorry - I mean the results need to be retrieved by code running on a separate machine (thinking C# or PowerShell).  It ultimately needs to be catered via SQL, to complicate things...  So I would like my SQL, on a separate server, to be able to essentially return the results of this function.

Comment: sounds like a candidate for a web service (wcf) component. the main difficulty I see is how to replicate the exact functionality of that vendor-specific code. For that it would help if we could see as much of that as possible. do you even have the full source of that component? Maybe even a "ported" solution completely in SQL would be possible?

Comment: or do you mean you want to consume that as a database query, so that in the end you just execute a SELECT statement? then the .NET integration of SQL server could help: you can write a user defined function in C#, compile that, register it in SQL server and expose it as a function callable from T-SQL statements, views and procedures.

Comment: I have the full source available.  Unfortunately, the software and this function perform some processing that does not lend itself to being completed in SQL (the tables are designed poorly), along with an unknown number of other validation checks being performed that it could be hard to account for.  We are working with a third-party for mobile integration, so the idea is that I would like this integration to function in as close of a way as possible to the actual live code.  [Here](http://pastebin.com/HkRAJaED) is the base function, without digging into classes.

Comment: I had no idea I could create a SQL function out of C#!?  That is definitely enticing, with a few caveats I can think of off the top of my head, 1) how to include the dependencies - are they carried through in the deployment?, 2) how to define the C# object input that this code is expecting within SQL.

Comment: but that stuff contains GUI code (error labels, error messages displayed, ...). I doubt that it could be reused like this at all. Looks like there is no way around making a proper shared component out of it.

Comment: Assuming I'm only concerned with whether it passed or not (and if not, why), couldn't I get away with stripping out the GUI components and just returning either "Success!" or result.ErrorXml?

Comment: sure. only it will no longer be the cheap solution you originally sought - no clean re-use, but adaptation. what if you used the ASP.NET frontend like you would use a web service? construct a `HttpRequest` (POST) and interpret the result.

Comment: I had thought about that, but there are things like a long .ASPXANONYMOUS cookie string in the header and a long garbled string parameter that I would have to figure out how to generate, as well as ensuring they're authenticated (maybe related to the cookie), and all that seems like it would be more convoluted then snagging the code in the asp.cs file.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call any functions in an ASP.NET codebehind file directly.

Your best bet is to copy and paste the code into your own project, if it is available to you.